# firebase auth security rule username missing

Tags: firebase, angularfire

Can't find it

https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/rule-expressions/auth.html
or https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-email-password.html

And in security page i saw:

https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/security-rules.html

```
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.username == 'admin'",
    ".write": "auth.username == 'admin'"
  }
```

And i would like to use in one of my security rules the user 's name like:

```
  "something"
     "$name": {
        ".write": "$name == auth.name" 
      }
```

Is the auth.username available by default? If not how can i access it in firebase security.

BTW:(i have a field "name" in my users "table" )

Comment: [Engineer at Firebase] Which Simple Login authentication method are you using here? The `username` attribute is only available for certain authentication methods.

Comment: Hello sir, i am using simple password login. I did an workaround with saving $id instead of $username but i am still curious about answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the email / password authentication method in Firebase Simple Login, the only attributes defined on the `auth` object in your security rules are the ones listed on https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-email-password.html under the `After Authenticating` heading.

This includes the following:

- **provider** - The authentication method used, in this case: `password`
  (*string*).
- **email** - The user's email address (*string*).
- **id** - The user's auto-incrementing id for your Firebase (*string*).
- **uid** - A unique id combining the provider and id, intended as the unique key for user data (*string*).